# Custom worflow to create a task for a each user in a group?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I've seen several people asking this question trhoughout the web, with no real solution.

Using SharePont 2007, and SharePoint Designer.

What I am attempting to do is to create a workflow which creates a task for each user in a group to review a document.

The current implementation in SharePoint seems to only create a single task for the group, and then anyone in that group can complete it for the entire group.

Yes I could add every person individually to the action, but then what if that group changes? People are removed or added, then I have to continually update the workflow everytime that occurs.

Is there a way to do this? Do I have to create a custom action?

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the task page:

- Save the response of the current user
- Check to see if all users from a group have provided a response

Comment: Well the response is actually going to be done in a discussion thread. The task item itself, I just want them to click on "Complete". I would much rather have the functionality of comments residing in the document library itself, which I have seen in codeplex as a project, but I cannot install any custom components.

But what do you mean by "Modify the task page"? Am I interpreting what you are trying to convey correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Before going into SharePoint Designer, have you considered the out of the box **Approval** workflow?